# BadTokenException in asynctask class for adding progressdialog in Tabs?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

Hi all In my application i am addiing progress dialog in asynctask class like the following.And this asynctask called in oncreate method.

```
class GettingData extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long>
        { 

protected void onPreExecute() 
            {
                dialog=MyProgressDialog.show(getParent(), null,null);
            }
@Override
            protected Long doInBackground(URL... arg0) {
                          try{


                             DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
                             HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(DataUrls.map);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost); 
                             HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity(); 
                             String response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
}catch(Exception e){
                             e.printStackTrace(); 
                          }

                return null;
            }
            protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {             
                try{
                Map_ExpandableAdapter mNewAdapter = new Map_ExpandableAdapter(MapViewActivity.this,groupItem, childItem,lstMenus,places);
                mNewAdapter.setInflater((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE),MapViewActivity.this);
                lstMenus.setAdapter(mNewAdapter);
//              lstMenus.setOnChildClickListener(MapViewActivity.this);

                UtilsListViewHeight.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(lstMenus);
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        }//closing asynchronous process
```

And this is the Progressdialog i am using

```
public class MyProgressDialog extends Dialog {

    public static MyProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
            CharSequence message) {
        return show(context, title, message, false);
    }
public MyProgressDialog(Context context) {
        super(context, R.style.NewDialog);
    }
}
```

In asynctask class i passed the instance **getParent()**,Because i am using tabs.But i got the error like this

Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@441cf040 is not valid; is your activity running?

So please suggest me what is the problem in this.Thanks to all InAdvanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says "Is your activity running"

You forgot to dismiss your dialog while
These events might have occurred

1. When you switched to a different activity without dismissing a already displayed  dialog 
   Solution :
   Before making a switch to a different activity make sure dialog is closed.
2. Or when an exception might have occurred and your activity got closed but the dialog was not closed..

Solution :
Call dismiss in your catch block as I see it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your're not passing the current Activity as the context ,rather you seem to be passing the parent of the current activity .

Replace

```
dialog=MyProgressDialog.show(getParent(), null,null);
```

with

```
dialog=MyProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, null,null);
```

where MyActivity is the name of the current activity.

Comment: I am using tabs.So i passed getparent()

Comment: My current activity is the child activity

Comment: You would need to enclose the post execute code within a condition like this
if( context!=null && !((Activity)context.isFinishing()){

}

Comment: But i am getting exception adding the progress dialog. i.e  dialog=MyProgressDialog.show(getParent(), null,null);

Comment: Could you update your code to enclose the activity/fragment youve written the async task in